# sed replace lines starting with and ending with specific words

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace lines starting with '#SERVICE' and ending in '///' with '#SERVICE 1:64:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:'
For example, this line:  '#SERVICE blablabla ///'
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
sed -i 's;#SERVICE*///;#SERVICE 1:64:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:;g'
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Provide some of the text that you are working with and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong. `E*` matches zero or more repetitions of `E`. To say `E` followed by anything, you want `E.*` (where `.` is a regex metacharacter which matches any character except newline).

This is a very common FAQ. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-pattern-and-regular-expression and more broadly [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](//stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).